# How to customize number of events per day in react-big-calendar?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-big-calendar

[image]

I have 4 events. What I want is that when I have more than 1 event, it will show 1 event and "+3 more".

Now its showing 2 events and "+2 more" by default and I dont know how to customize it.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Big Calendar doesn't work like that. According to the source code, it determines how many are displayed according to the amount of available space (you are supposed to set a height on it's container, according to the [documentation](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/story/about-big-calendar--page)), and then shows a link stating how many more `events` are on that day. Sounds like a great feature though. You should submit a PR.

Answer (score 0):

we solved this issue !!!

To customize the number of events per day in `react-big-calendar`, you can override the default styles using the following CSS:

```css
.rbc-row-content {
  min-height: 110px !important;
}

.rbc-month-row {
  overflow: visible !important;
}


/* Assuming your container div has a class named 'calendar-container' */
.calendar-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}



Make sure to replace `'calendar-container'` with the actual class name of your container div.

Remember to test your solution thoroughly and consider providing alternative approaches or explanations if applicable.


#k3tan #arkan
```